# Self-Tracking Entity Sets and comparing changes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

Im making .net application as a project on my Univeristy and I have a problem with Self-Tracking Entity Sets. I'm selecting an record, passing it through a wcf service, make some changes and pass it to the server again. There I want to compare what was changed, so Im selecting the same record from context once a again (this is the record with old values) and comparing. Then, after comparing I want to call ApplyChanges on context with entity passed via the service, and Im getting an error:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

I suppose it's because loading the same entity twice (before changes and after changes to compare). Is there any better way to compare changes(I need to make change history in another db table)? And wouldnt this error also apear if two clients gets the same record, and the first one changes it and wants to store into db? Im using .net 4.0.

Comment: pass DTOs to the WCF service, and save yourself lots of pain and hair.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed way to use STEs. STEs wrap a lot of logic but they are not able to handle [duplicate keys attached to context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2010/10/06/self-tracking-entities-applychanges-and-duplicate-entities.aspx).

So I can imagine two solutions:

- Do not load entity for comparing changes. Instead apply changes from your STE and handle [SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event (or override `SaveChanges` on context) to get applied changes from `ObjectStateManager`.
- Try to [detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx) loaded entity before you apply changes from STE.